# How to retrieve the start and end time from a log file(text file) using python

Tags: python, time

I have bunch of log files and I want to get the start and end time from all the log files and export to excel using python.The log file looks like this:

C:\Program Files\App.exe version 15.0.1711.3912 opened 12/09/19 10:08:13 on M40001A
[12/09/2019 10:08:13.723]`3`19772`LOW_FREQ`NORMAL`NONE`CONFIG`NONE`
[12/09/2019 10:08:13.727]`4`19772`LOW_FREQ`NORMAL`NONE`CONFIG`NONE`
[12/09/2019 10:08:13.727]`5`19772`LOW_FREQ`NORMAL`NONE`CONFIG`NONE`
[12/09/2019 10:08:13.727]`6`19772`LOW_FREQ`NORMAL`NONE`DATA`NONE`Pre-Exposure variable list is empty.
C:\Program Files\App.exe version 15.0.1711.3912 closed 12/09/19 10:21:11

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If all logs look the same and you already have load your file as `txt` the following code extract start and end time.

```py
txt = """C:\Program Files\App.exe version 15.0.1711.3912 opened 12/09/19 10:08:13 on M40001A [12/09/2019 10:08:13.723]319772LOW_FREQNORMALNONECONFIGNONE [12/09/2019 10:08:13.727]419772LOW_FREQNORMALNONECONFIGNONE [12/09/2019 10:08:13.727]519772LOW_FREQNORMALNONECONFIGNONE [12/09/2019 10:08:13.727]619772LOW_FREQNORMALNONEDATANONEPre-Exposure variable list is empty. C:\Program Files\App.exe version 15.0.1711.3912 closed 12/09/19 10:21:11"""

start = " ".join(txt.split("opened ")[1].split(" ")[:2])
end = " ".join(txt.split(" ")[-2:]) 
# end = txt[-17:] # alternative
```

For the second part you can list all the log files in your directory and extract start and end.

```py
def fun(txt):
    start = " ".join(txt.split("opened ")[1].split(" ")[:2])
    end = " ".join(txt.split(" ")[-2:])
    return [start, end]

lst = [f for f in  os.listdir("log_folder") if f[-4:]==".log"]
```

Now you need to loop `lst` open every file and apply `fun` to the text. Let's say that you have a fun `read_log` then you can

```py
out = [fun(read_log(f)) for f in lst]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=["start, "end"])
df.to_csv("from_logs.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the dates with something like this:

```
with open('file.log') as file:
    log = file.read()

    start = re.search(r'opened\s.*\son', log).group().replace('opened ', '').replace(' on', '')
    end = re.search(f'closed\s.*$', log).group().replace('closed ', '')

    print(f'Start: {start} End: {end}')
```

Which will get:

```
>>> Start: 12/09/19 10:08:13 End: 12/09/19 10:21:11
```